# If $Ω$ is a bounded domain and $K⊆Ω$ is compact, how can we define the restriction of a continuous linear functional $C^0(\overlineΩ)→ℝ$ to $C^0(K)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, finite-element-method

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain and $K\subseteq\Omega$ be compact. In [Remark B.23 of *Finite Element Methods for Incompressible Flow Problems*](https://books.google.de/books?id=yKZlDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA709&lpg=PA709&dq=%22Global+and+Local+Functionals%22+%22The+restriction+of+the+functionals+to%22&source=bl&ots=d9ed2xCqMC&sig=s1lHJyi6Umsd2wQ--xclEbbFm7k&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKpPv0vtPSAhUDOhQKHZjUCcwQ6AEIHjAA) the author is writing about the restriction of a continuous linear $\Phi:C^0(\overline\Omega)\to\mathbb R$ to $C^0(K)$.

> How is such a restriction defined?

It's clear that, by [*Tietze's extension theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), any function from $C^0(K)$ can be extended to $C^0(\overline\Omega)$. However, such an extension is not unique and hence I have no idea how $\Phi$ can be restricted to $C^0(K)$.

Let me note that, in the context of the book, $\Phi(p)$ might be the evaluation of $p\in C^0(\overline\Omega)$ at some point $x\in\overline\Omega$. So, if $x\not\in K$, then the nonuniqueness of the formerly mentioned extensions should be a problem.

Comment: Are $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$ the same set?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes, sorry, I'm used to denote the domain by $\Lambda$, since I preserve the symbol $\Omega$ usually for a sample space. But here I wanted to stick to the notation of the book.

Comment: @daw Didn't you notice that I explicitly noted that particular structure? Denote the restriction you've mentioend by $\Phi_K$. Is $\Phi_K$ a continuous functional $C^0(K)\to\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).

> **Theorem:** Suppose $X$ is locally-compact. Every linear functional on $C^0(X)$ is of the form $\displaystyle f \mapsto \int _Xf(x) d \mu (x)$ for some (signed) Borel measure  $\mu$ on $X$.

So given a functional $\Phi$ on $C^0(\overline \Omega)$ we get a measure $\mu$ on $\overline \Omega$. We then define the measure $\nu$ on $K$ to be the restriction of $\mu$ to $K$. This allows us to define the functional $\Psi$  given by $\displaystyle g \mapsto \int _K g(y) d \nu (y)$ on $C^0(K)$.

In case $\Psi$ is evaluation at some point $x \in \overline \Omega - K$ the corresponding measure is the point-measure at $x$. The restriction of that measure to $K$ is the zero measure and we get $\Psi \colon C^0(K) \to \mathbb R$ is the zero functional.

**Edit**: It feels like $\Psi$ should be obtainable from $\Phi$ in the following manner: Given a continuous function $f$ on $K$ define the  function $g$ on $\overline \Omega$ to coincide with $f$ over $K$ and to be zero elsewhere. We cannot just define $\Psi(f) = \Phi(g)$ because $g$ is most likely not continuous. So instead choose any series of continuous functions $g_n$ on $\overline \Omega$ that converges pointwise to $g$. Define $\Psi (f) = \lim \Phi(g_n)$

Comment: How did you use [Riesz' representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) to obtain your theorem?

Comment: The theorem now linked in the answer is also commonly called the Reisz Representation Theorem

Comment: @Daron I didn't know that. Thank you four your answer and the link. I will take a look at it and accept as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The space $C^0(K)$ is commonly defined as the collection of all $f \in C(\mathbb R^d)$ whose support is a subset of $K$.  If $K \subset \Omega$ then you have $$C^0(K) \subset C^0(\overline \Omega)$$ and the term "restriction" has an unambiguous meaning.